# Не работает приложение на redmi 3s, в чём причина?

Tags: java, android

Недавно, столкнулся с проблемой. От одного из пользователей, купившего моё приложение в google play пришло сообщение что приложение не работает на redmi 3s.

Проблема заключается в том, что у меня нет совершенно никаких идей, в чём может быть причина. Как сообщил пользователь, ошибка возникает при нажатии на кнопку, по которой происходит переход в активность со следующим кодом:

```java
package com.magical3000.sweet_dreams;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;

public class activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
        Dreaming();
    }

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    int i=0, limit=90, nowsound=R.raw.relax, check=0;

    public void onClicka1(View view) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, ChooseActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void Dreaming() {
        mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, nowsound);
        mPlayer.start();
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Dreaming1();
            }
        });
    }

    private void Dreaming1() {
        if (i<limit)
        {
            i=i+1;
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        else
        {
            if (check==0 || check==2 || check==4)
            {
                Dreaming2();
            }
            else {
                if (check == 1 || check == 3) {
                    Dreaming3();
                }
                else {
                    if (check == 5) {
                        i = 0;
                        limit = 90;
                        nowsound = R.raw.relax;
                        mPlayer.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Dreaming2() {
        check=check+1;
        nowsound=R.raw.sleep1;
        i=0;
        limit=270;
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    private void Dreaming3() {
        check=check+1;
        nowsound=R.raw.sleep2;
        i=0;
        limit=270;
        mPlayer.start();
    }

}
```

Помогите пожалуйста вычислить причину ошибки и устранить её.

Comment: из информации в вашем вопросе с уверенностью можно сказать только то, что конвенцию Java по оформлению кода вы не читали, так как имена классов пишутся с большой буквы, имена же методов, наоборот, с маленькой. По самой же проблеме с такой же уверенностью можно сказать,  что в вопросе нет никакой информации, которая помогла бы хоть приблизительно сказать, в чем у вас дело. Вам нужно получить стектрейс с проблемного устройства при падении вашего приложения, в котором и будет, собственно, написано, в чем именно проблема.

Comment: получить стектрейс при краше на клиентскм устройстве можно в аналитике google вашего аккаунта разработчика или с помощью сервисов, вроде ACRA, Crashlytics . Полученный стектрейс при краше нужно добавить в вопрос и тогда можно будет хоть что то сказать о том, в чем проблема

Comment: Думаю, это именно из - за прошивки MIU. В